# Active state not working only for first time visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu with few links. I just want to highlight my current link so I used this code for active state. It's working fine.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5q73o1g/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.nav li a').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass('home-active-link');
        }
    });
});
```

**The problem**
When I put it on localhost and tested. It's not working on first time visit. Please take a look at this screenshot.

[image]

But when I browse pages and back to home, it works fine. Any suggestions for fixing this?

[image]

Comment: Can you put the code inside a jQuery(document).ready(function($){   setTimeout(function(){  },30);  });  with a small setTimeout value, Then console.log the window.location.href to see if any extra slashes appear in the string comparison

Comment: How do I console log window.location.href ?

Comment: I ll add in the answer  , please check

Comment: Tested. No any  extra slashes appear in the string comparison

Comment: Both console.log values are same ?

Comment: ah no, it's showing ---- http://localhost/test/index.html
http://localhost/test/
http://localhost/test/member-list.html
http://localhost/test/ --- like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204344/discussion-between-ajith-and-janath).

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the code as given below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.nav li a').each(function () {

        console.log($(this).prop('href')); // alert($(this).prop('href'))
        console.log(window.location.href); // alert(window.location.href); 


        if ($(this).prop('href') === window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass('home-active-link');
        }
    });
    },30);
});
```